# Associate a downloadable product to configurable product

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, configurable-product, downloadable, associate-products

**How to associate a downloadable product to configurable product?**

I can see only simple product list filtered with the similar attribute set right now. but not downloadable product with the same attribute set of configurable product.

Why can't I able to associate a downloadable product to configurable product?

I tried by altering the following setting after [reading this blog](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-downloadable-products-not-displayed-in-associated-products-tab-in-grouped-product/).

```
Downloadable product -> Downloadable information -> Links -> Links can be purchased separately -> No
```

I think the above trick will work only for Grouped products but not for configurable products.

What should I do?

Please help.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8562/142). Solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

There could be two reasons that a downloadable product does not show up on the grid, both can be diagnosed by looking at the function `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid::_prepareCollection`

1. The downloadable product type is not allowed as a configurable,
2. The downloadable product has some required fields,

Firstly normally in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/etc/config.xml` there is a setting that allows downloadable product to be set configurable. You should make sure this is set and not overridden by anything else.

```
<configurable>
    <allow_product_types>
        <downloadable/>
    </allow_product_types>
</configurable>
```

Secondly if the downloadable product has some required options then it will not be available to be used, note that this covers all product types and not just downloadable.

This `required_options` value is set, for downloadable products, if the link selection can be purchased separately. So setting the links to be purchased seperatly to "no" will allow downloadable products to be used with configurable products.

```
if ($this->getLinkSelectionRequired($product)) {
    $this->getProduct($product)->setTypeHasRequiredOptions(true);
} else {
    $this->getProduct($product)->setTypeHasRequiredOptions(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to upload at least 1 file, otherwise the option will turn gray in the frontend. Good luck.