# Standard & Digital product of the same article

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1.9, downloadable

I am setting up a book store with Magento. My client will be selling both e-books and printed books. I want to know if I can set up a product and the visitors will choose from the product's page what format they want it to buy: printed or digital.
So if a visitor will pick up the printed version, he will pay the price of X$, fill in the order form and the book will be delivered to him.
Instead if he will choose a digital book, after the payment he will be able to download the book. And no book will be delivered to him :)

Can Magento do this?

Comment: Nice question by the way!

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box there are these **product types** to match your needs:

- Downloadable products (the e-books in various formats)
- Simple products (the printend book)
- Configurable products (add simple products to a configurable one to select from options)

Per default you can just **add simple products to configurable products**. There is already an answer from David on how to add downloadable products to configurables: [Associate a downloadable product to configurable product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17959/associate-a-downloadable-product-to-configurable-product)

What you will need to consider is how to **match the different product attributes**. The printed one might have attributes such as pages, cover, weight whereas the downloadable won't have them.